# Dealing with online newspaper headline link in PHP

Tags: php

I have seen on most online newspaper websites that when i click on a headline link, e.g. `two thieves caught red handed`, it normally opens a url like this: `www.example.co.uk/news/two-thieves-caught-red-handed`.

How do I deal with this url in php code, so that I can only pick the last part in the url. e.g. `two-thieves-caught-red-handed`. After that I want to work with this string.

I know how to deal with `GET` parameters like "www.example.co.uk/news/headline=two thieves caught red handed".
But I do not want to do it that way. Could you show me another way.

Comment: Are you using different url from time to time?

Comment: You could use `explode('/',$url);` and then it's just the last part of that new array that contains your "two-thieves ... "

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of explode and end functions for that

for example:

```
<?php
$url = "www.example.co.uk/news/two-thieves-caught-red-handed";
$url = explode('/', $url);

$end = end($url);
echo "$end";
?>
```

The code will result

```
two-thieves-caught-red-handed
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options in php to get the current url. For a detailed overview look [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

One would be to use `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and the use a string manipulation function for extraction of the parts you need.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) thread will help you too.